# How do we calculate the distribution function at each interval?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

We have a coin that we throw twice. If $X$ is the random variable that represent the number of heads.

I want to find the distribution function $F_X(x)$ in the intervals  $0<x, \ 0\leq x<1, \ 1\leq x<2$.

The results of the coin are the following:

- TT
- TH
- HT
- HH

How could we calculate $F_X(x)$ at each interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ is discrete, we have $X=0,1$ or $2$.

By definition, 
$$F_X(x)=P(X \leq x)$$
if $x<0$, $P(X \leq x)=0$ because $X$ cannot be strictly negative.

if $0 \le x <1$, $P(X \leq x)$ is the probability that $X=0$, which is $\frac{1}{4}$

if $1 \le x <2$, $P(X \leq x)$ is the probability that $X=1$ or $X=0$, which is $\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}=\frac{3}{4}$

Comment: Ahh ok!! If we have the interval $x\geq 2$, we have that $P(X\leq x)$ is the probability $X=0$ or $X=1$ or $X=2$, so $\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}=1$, right?

Comment: That's correct !

Comment: Great!! Thank you!! :-)